# How to get the max value in every group of n rows using AWK?

Tags: parsing, awk

Say I have the following 3 columns in text file:

```
1 003 3  
2 006 1  
3 005 4  
4 001 2  
5 006 7  
6 002 2  
7 004 3  
8 001 6  
9 002 8  
10 005 2
```

I want to output 3 columns:

- last sequence number in every group of 3,
- $2 of the max $3 value in every group,
- and the max $3 in every group.

Starting from after the first one. So from that input, the output would be:

```
1 003 3  
4 005 4  
7 006 7  
10 002 8
```

What I tried:

```
awk \
        'BEGIN{
                cnt=3;
                max=0;
        };

        {
                if (cnt == 3){
                        cnt++;
                        max_arr[cnt]=$3;
                        for (i in max_arr){
                                if (max_arr[i] > max)
                                        { max = max_arr[i] }
                        }

                        printf "%s %s %s\n", $1,$2,max;
                        cnt=1;
                        delete max_arr;
                        max=0;
                }
                else{
                        cnt++;
                        max_arr[cnt]=$3;
                }
}' input_file.txt
```

This gives me:

```
1 003 3  
4 001 4  
7 004 7  
10 005 8
```

Column 1 and 3 are correct, but 2 is wrong.

Comment: Could you explain what you expect a little bit clearly? Describe the meaning of output columns again, please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how you do it robustly:

```
$ cat tst.awk
{
    isBlockBeg = ( (NR%3)==2 )
    isBlockEnd = ( (NR%3)==1 )
}
isBlockBeg { max=$3 }
$3 >= max  { max=$3; val=$2 }
isBlockEnd { print $1, val, max }
END { if (!isBlockEnd) print $1, val, max }

$ awk -f tst.awk file
1 003 3
4 005 4
7 006 7
10 002 8
```

Note that the above will work whether your data is numbers or strings, whether or not your data is all-negative, and even if your data doesn't end nicely at the end of a block of 3. If you don't need that last part, you can reduce it to just:

```
$ cat tst.awk
(NR%3)==2 { max=$3 }
$3 >= max { max=$3; val=$2 }
(NR%3)==1 { print $1, val, max }

$ awk -f tst.awk file
1 003 3
4 005 4
7 006 7
10 002 8
```

Comment: All answers worked for me but I picked yours because it takes care of the end. I didn't put this in my requirements but I actually needed that. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You could try the following awk script :

```
# file : script.awk

# if max[1] is uninitialized OR ...
# if the 3rd field of our current line is > than the one stored in our max array ...
# we store the 2nd and 3rd field of our line in the array
!(1 in max) || max[1]<$3 { max[0]=$2; max[1]=$3; }

# if the remainder of our line_number / 3 == 1 (lines 4, 7, 10, ...)
NR % 3 == 1 {
    # we print the line_number, and the 2 max values
    print NR,max[0],max[1]

    # we delete the old array
    delete max
}
```

You can then call it like this : `awk -f script.awk data`

Sample input :

```
> cat data
1 003 3
2 006 1
3 005 4
4 001 2
5 006 7
6 002 2
7 004 3
8 001 6
9 002 8
10 005 2
```

Sample output :

```
> awk -f script.awk data
1 003 3
4 005 4
7 006 7
10 002 8
```

Comment: Nice! Some comments would help. Note `NR==1 { ... }` is the same -and more idiomatic- as `if (NR==1) { ... }`. Also, you can paste the script in a file and call it with `awk -f script.awk data`.

Comment: Ok, I must have done some wrong tests before, as it was displaying the correct output even with negative values . However, you are indeed right. I edited my answer to test for empty max[1].

Answer (score 2):

A shorter awk script could be this one:

```
awk 'm<$3{m=$3;n=$2} !((NR+2)%3){print $1,n,m;m=n=""}' file
```

where the max value of column 3 is `m`, the corresponding value of column 2 is `n`.

The statement `!((NR+2)%3)` is executed for the first line and every next 3 lines, which print the wanted value and unset both the max value of column 3 `m` and `n`.

Comment: In order to handle negative numbers, you could write `m=n=""` instead. Also, `NR%3==1` is both shorter and easier to understand than `!((NR+2)%3)`, so there's no real reason to replace it :)

Comment: When doing min/max calculations, always seed with the first value read so your code will work even when the max is less than zero, for example.

Answer (score 1):

if $3 values are all positive...

```
$ awk '$3>m3   {m3=$3; v2=$2} 
       NR%3==1 {print $1,v2,m3; m3=0}' file

1 003 3
4 005 4
7 006 7
10 002 8
```